# MOSS SP3 - How to uninstall Language Pack?

Tags: 2007, deployment

I no longer need to support a language pack on my MOSS SP3, Aug 12 CU server.  I have tried to remove it from Control Panel but it is unable to uninstall the Hotfix for WSS (KB2687331).  How can I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KB2687331 is a SharePoint cumulative hotfix. Cumulative hotfixes and service packs in SharePoint cannot be uninstalled once deployed. This is because  every update makes changes to the database schema which cannot be undone.

The language packs themselves should be able to be uninstalled from the control panel however. A cumulative hotfix however contains all available languages (service packs don't).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This is my problem.  The hotfix is listed under the language pack (as though it has been applied to the language pack) and therefore it won't uninstall from Control Panel. It has uninstalled all the Office hotfixes which were listed against it but not this WSS Aug 12 CU.  Do I have to assume from this that something specific to the language pack has been altered in the database and therefore support for it can no longer be removed?